# Text inside QML TextArea becomes invisible when a specific character (e.g., ￼) is inserted

Tags: unicode, qml, textarea

I have a C++ and QML application with a `TextArea` component used for user input. However, I encountered an issue where the text inside the `TextArea` becomes completely invisible when I attempt to insert a specific character, in this case, ￼ (Unicode symbol "object replacement character").

If I remove this character, the text becomes visible again. Surprisingly, even though the text is not visible, I can still move the cursor over the area where the text should be.

I have tried various solutions to resolve the problem, such as changing the font, using Unicode codes for the symbol (\uFFFC and ￼), and updating Qt to the latest version, but none of them worked. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```js
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    TextArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        text: "Sample text with ￼" // Text becomes invisible due to the ￼ symbol
        // Other properties and settings
    }
}
```

I expected the text to be visible regardless of the characters inserted into the `TextArea`. Could you please help me understand why the text becomes invisible when I insert the ￼ symbol and provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: That sounds totally broken. Have you tried the same code on a difference platform / device? Alternatively, have you tried a different component, e.g. TextEdit instead of TextArea? What happens when you change the QT_OPENGL environment variable to change how the graphics are rendered at runtime?

Comment: Tested on Windows 7 and 10, same issue - text becomes invisible. Changing QT_OPENGL (AA_UseDesktopOpenGL, AA_UseOpenGLES, AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL) didn't resolve the issue. Tried different components, TextArea and TextEdit both affected, but TextField and TextInput work fine (it is displayed as an empty character, which is similar to a space). The problem seems to be related to QML. In this regard, perhaps I need to create a bug?

Comment: It appears to be a bug.

Comment: If you use `validator` you can block the special character, e.g. `TextField { text: "Sample text"; validator: RegularExpressionValidator { regularExpression: /^[\w ]*$/ } }`

Comment: I have created a bug for this issue - https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-115633.